# How to effectively program my Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, loops

I got some `JLabel` and wanted to `setText`:

```
private JLabel jlA1B1;
private JLabel jlA1B2;
private JLabel jlA1B3;

private JLable jlA2B1;
private JLable jlA2B2;
private JLable jlA2B3;

private JLable jlA3B1;
private JLable jlA3B2;
private JLable jlA3B3;
```

So the **pattern is `jlA[x]B[y]`**. Is it possible to create some sort of loop to program this pattern? For example:

```
for(int i=1; i<4; i++;){
    for(int j=1; j<4; j++;){
        jlA[i]B[j].setText(i);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Use an array to store the JLable.

Comment: `private JLabel jlA1B3;

private JLable jlA2B1;` Please copy/paste actual compilable code, rather than 'something like' code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your labels into a two-dimensional array and loop over the array.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down-voted, and array would be the obvious & easiest  solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No fully functional, document, runnable solution, which can be copied and pasted ... but since the original question fails to provide those details, I have no issue with the question not providing them +1 from me